# How to mount a device of host to host in a Docker container?

Tags: docker

I have a Linux host with a block device `/dev/sdb` , and I want to mount the device to host's `/mnt/sdb`.

My special need is that do this in a container but not in the host itself, and need not to mount the device into container also (for example `-v`).

For example (does not work certainly):

```
$ docker run some-image mount /dev/sdb /mnt/sdb
```

Or absolutely this is impossible?

Answer (score 10):

Docker supports adding/passing through devices to a container:

```
docker run --device=/dev/sdb
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#add-host-device-to-container-device

Comment: [Not possible on macOS](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/6076/3) (as the daemon runs inside a VM).

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to mount that device (outside docker), and then use said mounted folder in your docker run.
See [issue 21485](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/21485#issuecomment-220002820) as an illustration:

```
mount /dev/sdb /workspace
docker run --rm -v "/workspace:/workspace" some-image
```

Comment: All what I want to do is like this https://github.com/opencontainers/runc/pull/77#issuecomment-127216464 , mount a device to host from in a container.